# The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required in windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

While running below code i got "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required." issue. I did lots of RND but still facing same problem...

Code:

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient
    Try
        web_client.UseDefaultCredentials = True

        web_client.DownloadFile(txtRemoteFile.Text, txtLocalFile.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Done")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim wp As WebProxy
        wp = New WebProxy("ProxyIP", ProxyPort)
        wp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("LoginName", "Password", "DomainName")
        web_client.Proxy = wp
        web_client.DownloadFile(txtRemoteFile.Text, txtLocalFile.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you're changing the credentials in your `Catch` block, shouldn't you also be changing the `UseDefaultCredentials` to `False` in order to use them?

Comment: Can you download the file from a browser?

Comment: @sblandin: yes, i can download file from browser...

Comment: Maybe you are incurring in the behaviour described in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.100%29.aspx The user of your browser is not the same running the ASP.NET process.

Comment: @KenWhite.. Thanks for your reply.. I change the code according to you... but still facing same issue....

Comment: I created one web service and copy paste above code into that service and in web.config file of that service i added below code..
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>.. and it works... but i don't understand why above code is not working in windows application

Comment: Hi guys.. any idea... why above code is not working....